# Will trading up StatTraks give me a StatTrak?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

If I fill my trade up contract with Stat Trek weapons only, will I get a StatTrak in return? Or can I use only one StatTrak in the whole process and still get a StatTrak back?
Or does this not affect the trade at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, using stattrak weapons in a trade up contract will guarantee a stattrak skin.

Answer (score 1):

As of the [update for the game on 3/31/2015](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2015/03/11734/):

> - Trade up contracts work on StatTrak weapons.

StatTraks can be mixed with normal weapons, and here's the interesting part; StatTrak weapons can come from a trade-up contract.

Answer (score -1):

You can now. NEW UPDATE lets you trade up stattrak

Comment: What happens if you mix stattraks with normal weapons?